# Creating a membership app that connects to a database , what should I be studying?

Tags: android, database, http, social-networking

I'm getting pretty good at Android and I'm ready to take the next step towards my goal. I'm creating a social networkish social app that will require a user logins and connects to a database to pull user info.

I have been focused on the app side of things up until now. Where do I even start with something like this? what should I be studying?

I'm looking for keywords, tutorials, videos,the secret sauce to making a mobile service. What are the standards currently? what kind of databases are Foursquare and Pandora using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for the app side, you should look at java OAuth examples for authentication.

http://code.google.com/p/oauth/

Answer (score 0):

I'd start here: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/11/your-internet-drivers-license.html

If you can avoid writing your own authentication/authorization mechanism, you'll be better off, it will be more secure, and you will also be helping to stop issues outlined in [this related article](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/05/openid-does-the-world-really-need-yet-another-username-and-password.html).

**Edit - Added**

Then my next step would be here for a practical how-to: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/app-builder/integrate-facebook-logins-in-your-android-app/296?tag=nl.e055